# Docker index html file page takes too long to respond

Tags: html, angular, docker, nginx, static-files

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
COPY -r dist/ /var/www/html/
CMD service nginx start && tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Then :

```
docker build -t fire . 
docker run -p 4000:80 -d -t fire
```

default.conf :

```
listen 80;
server_name _;
root /var/www/html/
index index.htm index.html 

location /{

}
```

It looks okay.The files are copied but on opening remote server on port 4000 , site cant be reached,the page takes too long to respond.Any Solutions?

Expected index html served on there

Comment: Please post the docker and nginx logs which will be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @SuchandraT it has no logs... just says " starting nginx..."

Answer (score 0):

Fridah, there is an issue with your nginx conf

to Check if nginx conf is a valid file.

```
nginx -t
```

This should return error with your current conf.

Working config file:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;     
        }       
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: still not working with that new config.... the container is up but cant show on the browser. Also nginx -t says nginx.conf is ok. test successful

Comment: what network looks like? host ip, container ip.

Comment: what do you mean?am not well versed with docker networks?